# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 201: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I am trying to read a csv file using pandas but an error is coming. I have read the answers in stack overflow but my problem is not matched with it.

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 201: invalid start byte

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('property.csv')
```

Comment: Please provide sample input so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The error means the file isn't UTF-8-encoded.  Figure out the encoding and specify it in the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) command.  0x80 is a Windows-1252-encoded Euro sign, so that's one possible encoding if offset 201 in the file is expected to be a Euro symbol.

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is an error in the encoding of the file.

[`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?#pandas.read_csv) has two parameters which affect encoding:

> encoding: str, optional
> Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. ‘utf-8’). [List of Python standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

> encoding_error: str, optional, default “strict”
> How encoding errors are treated. [List of possible values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

The simplest way to read through your file is probably to set `encoding` to `"cp1252"`, the default encoding on windows (for instance CSV exports of Excel sheets).

```py
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd

buf = BytesIO("""\
h1,h2
€,euro
""".encode("cp1252"))

pd.read_csv(buf, encoding="cp1252")

# encoding defaults to utf-8 on linux/macos
# pd.read_csv(buf, encoding="utf-8")  # UnicodeDecodeError
```

NB. I use a [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to avoid writing a file, keep pointing to the file you have as usual.